# Django and jQuery Quiz Use Model in script

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to use jQuery with model objects in my template. I want to see if the radio button they chose is equal to the correct answer attribute. My code runs, but it doesn't do anything. For example, "if {answerA} equals {correctAnswer} then add a point'

```
{% extends "mainpage/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Multiple Choice</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#quiz').on('change', function(){
        //  if the id of a button equals the correct answer
        if($('input[name=optradio]:checked', '#quiz').val() === '4'){
          alert($('input[name=optradio]:checked','#quiz').val());
        }
      })
    })
</script>
</head>
{% csrf_token %}
<html>
<p>{{ title }}</p>
<div class="container">
   <form method="GET" class="QuestionForm" id="quiz">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="A">{{answerA}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="B">{{answerB}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="C">{{answerC}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="D">{{answerD}}</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ok, but how would I pull in the data from it?

Comment: If the user is right, I want to show 1/1 and 0/1 if they're wrong. For example, if they chose button A and it equals the correct answer how do I gather that?

Comment: You have not specified a `value` attribute for your radio inputs

Comment: ok I'm trying to set the value equal to what's in the curly brackets

Comment: From the Django model

Comment: So. what have you got?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried to add  value attribute to your inputs?

Comment: Would I set it to {answerA}?

Comment: try it with `{{answerA}}` and you could use `on change` since your form does not have any inputs except radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the **value** attribute :

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" id="B" value="{{answerA}}"> {{answerA}}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, I'm not sure how to pass that back through Django

Comment: To be honest i am not that good with `django` but i can help you with jquery here is a [blog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) you may take a look at. sorry about that.

Comment: that's ok. I'm taking it one step at a time. I'll check out the blog, thanks!

Comment: If I have further questions, I'll post a comment if that is ok

Comment: One last question lol I'm trying to figure out if the user clicks the correct radio button to alert them it's correct, but it alerts on every radio button choice

Comment: Yes it's OK but always search for your question on google probably `99%` of what you will ask already has been answered and I really encourage you to watch the youtube tutorials there is a lot out there. after that if you still have a question you can ask a new one since it has been already answered.

Comment: that's probably because you forgot and add `{{ answerA }}` to all your value attributes , right?

Comment: No, I added that

Comment: try `if($('input[name=optradio]:checked').val() === 4)` not `if($('input[name=optradio]:checked', '#quiz').val() === '4')`                            
    or you can simply `if( $("form:radio:checked").val() === 4)`

Comment: It doesn't work, but i'll look into it and post a solution

Comment: No it's ok i am here to help you try to comment your check and only alert the value to check what value you get `alert($('input[name=optradio]:checked').val());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139069/discussion-between-amr-aly-and-ashley).